# Converting objective-C function to Swift's version

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have some difficulty converting my code to Swift. Could some guru out there kindly lend some helping hand? = )

```
- (void)insertNewItemWithTable:(AWSDynamoDBObjectModel<AWSDynamoDBModeling> *)object 
                    completion:(void(^)(BOOL error))complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift Version of your code:

```
func insertNewItemWithTable(object: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel<AWSDynamoDBModeling>, completion complete: (error: Bool) -> Void) {

}
```

Try this: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code

Comment: You are missing the requirement that the argument is conforms to the protocol `AWSDynamoDBModeling`.

Comment: the completion part is also not working. I had managed to do for the first argument:

func insertNewItem<T: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel where T: AWSDynamoDBModeling>(table: T?) {}

Comment: first argument is working and no error. The second argument is not which I need it when I call AWSTask (multithread operation)

Comment: Call the method, then just double click on each default blue popups. Like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jh323h3u395pf3x/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-03%20at%2012.19.39%20PM.png?dl=0